# Scanner in a while loop, loop won't quit

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I want to get input from the user which is either 1 or 2 and propmpt the user for the answer again if he doesn't comply with the right answer.

I tried doing it with a while loop:

```
    int players = 0;
    players = sc.nextInt();

    while (players != 1 || players != 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong input, choose again:");
        players = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(players);
    }
```

and a do-while:

```
    do
    {
        players = sc.nextInt();
    }
    while (players != 1 || players!= 2);
```

But the loop never quits, even when I input the right number.

And this logic used to work with scanf in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
players != 1 || players != 2
```

this condition is always true. `||` means `or`. So the expression is true if at least one of its two operands is true

- if players is 1, then `players != 2` is true, so the whole expression is true
- if players is 2, then `players != 1` is true, so the whole expression is true
- if players is anything else, then both expressions are true.

You want `&&`, not `||`.

Answer (score 1):

`players != 1 || players!= 2` is always true and should be `players != 1 && players!= 2`. I seriously doubt this wrong logic worked with C !

If you know a little about boolean algebra, you must know that `not(not(A) or not(B)) <=> A and B`. In your case, it means that the negation of your condition (which must be true for the loop to exit) is `players == 1 && players == 2`, which is trivially impossible.